# Angular2 and express - traceur 404 (Not Found) from system.src.js

Tags: angularjs, angular

In my express, I have the following config to serve static js files.

```
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
```

and the link I am at is http://localhost:3000/user/

user.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="acApp">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Responsive Onepage HTML Template | Multi</title>
    <!-- core CSS -->
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/userpage.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/ico/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-144-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-114-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-72-precomposed.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-57-precomposed.png">
    <!-- Angular 2 starts -->
        <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="/scripts/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>   
    <script src="/scripts/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script> 
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      console.log('reach system.config');
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('../js/acApp/main.ts')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="acApp">

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <mainRouter></mainRouter>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/mousescroll.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/smoothscroll.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

it throws error

```
system.src.js:1085 GET http://localhost:3000/user/traceur 404 (Not Found)
```

In chrome developer tool, the GET is fired by system.src.js as an ajax call,

```
  xhr.open("GET", url, true);

  if (xhr.setRequestHeader) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/x-es-module, */*');
    // can set "authorization: true" to enable withCredentials only
    if (authorization) {
      if (typeof authorization == 'string')
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', authorization);
      xhr.withCredentials = true;
    }
  }

  if (doTimeout) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      xhr.send();
    }, 0);
  } else {
    xhr.send(null);
  }
```

When I am doing the debugging, the first time it is to get

```
http://localhost:3000/js/acApp/main.ts
```

which is the correct path. Any idea why for traceur, it is 404?

**UPDATE**

Folder structure:

```
-node_modules
-public
--js
---acApp
----main.ts
----app.component.js
-views
--user.ejs
-routes
--user.js
-server.js
```

Inside of server.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, your SystemJS configuration doesn't seem to be correct. You configured a `app` root folder for your module files. This means that the specified configuration only applies when module names start with `app`.

In your case, it seems that such files are located under the `js` folder. So I would update this configuration this way:

```
System.config({
  map: {
    acApp: '../js/acApp'
  },
  packages: {        
    acApp: {
      format: 'register',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
});
System.import('acApp/main')
   .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
```

If your `user` folder is located under the `acApp`, this should work. Otherwise you need to configure another entry for this folder into the `packages` block...

Comment: Thanks Thierry. I have updated with my folder structure.  Now the 404 errors happen for system.src.js:1085 GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/platform/browser 404 (Not Found)  and system.src.js:1085 GET http://localhost:3000/user/angular2/router 404 (Not Found)

Comment: For `angular2/router`, you need to include the `router.dev.js` file in addition to the `angular2.dev.js` one.

Comment: For `angular2/platform/browser` including the `angular2.dev.js` should be enough? Do you have a 404 when loading it?

Comment: Thierry, I am curious that  why it is to GET http://localhost:3000/user/angular2/router and http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/platform/browser. Based on my express config, these two links are definitely 404

Comment: In fact, it's an issue with SystemJS. When there is no explicitly registered module with `System.register` (what is done within files `angular2.dev.js` and `router.dev.js`), SystemJS tries to load them from an URL. It deduces the URL from the current path where the import is done. For example for the first one, you probably try to import `angular2/router` within a component located under `localhost:3000/user`...

Comment: router one is fixed  by including router.dev.js, but system.src.js:1085 GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/platform/browser 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Great! Could you provide the content of `main.ts` and the new content of the `user.ejs` file?

Comment: After changing back to import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser' in main.ts, it is working now. Thanks Thierry.